# Add custom header above all-day in day view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm developing an application using FullCalendar, where I need to add a custom table header to the basic day view. I have tried and googled, but I aa unable to get the solution.

This is the code I have so far.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'basicDay',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    views: {
        day: {
            eventLimit: false
        },
        month: {
            eventLimit: true
        }
    },
    eventLimit: true,
    events: [
    {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2017-07-01'
    },
    {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2017-07-07',
        end: '2017-07-10'
    },
    {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2017-07-09T16:00:00'
    },
    {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2017-07-16T16:00:00'
    }
    ]
});
```

And I'm trying to add the title for the table contents using the following code

```
if ($('.fc-view.fc-basicDay-view.fc-basic-view')) {
    alert("Found");
    var thr = '<div class="fc-row1 fc-widget-header1"><table><thead><tr>' +
        '<th>Event</th></tr></thead></table></div>'

    console.log($(thr));

    $(thr).insertAfter('div.fc-day-grid');
} else {
    alert('No');
}
```

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't that work? Can you share the code you have so far ? Thanks

Comment: I will update the question asked.

Comment: I recommend you to give an example for this problem in jsfiddle. It is easier (for us) to check the whole problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Just a few things missing:

1. You should choose a better element to place the bar
2. You need to have the code on [`viewRender`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/), otherwise you'll lose the bar when you change the days / views
3. That code can only be added to the `basicDay` and `agendaView`. Eventually you can add specific bars to the other views, if you want.

So, you should add something like this to viewRender:

```
viewRender: function( view, element ) {
    if (view.name !== 'agendaDay' && view.name !== 'basicDay') {
        return false;
    }

    var html = '<div class="fc-day-grid fc-unselectable">' +
            '<div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content" style="border-right-width: 1px; margin-right: 16px;">' +
                '<div class="fc-bg">' +
                    '<table>' +
                        '<tbody>' +
                            '<tr>' +
                                '<td class="fc-axis fc-widget-content" style="width: 45px;"><span>Time</span></td>' +
                                '<td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-state-highlight events-label">Event</td>' +
                            '</tr>' +
                        '</tbody>' +
                    '</table>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="fc-content-skeleton">' +
                    '<table>' +
                        '<tbody>' +
                            '<tr>' +
                                '<td class="fc-axis" style="width:45px"></td>' +
                                '<td></td>' +
                            '</tr>' +
                        '</tbody>' +
                    '</table>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    $(".fc-body").find(".fc-widget-content:first").prepend(html);
}
```

You can then add some styles to `.events-label`. And you probably can remove some of the default classes of Fullcalendar.

See working example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/milz/hesj5d2x/).